# String Needs to Contain 2 words

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a textbox on one of my views, and that textbox should not accept anything that has more than 2 words or less than 2 words. This textbox needs 2 words.

Basically this textbox accepts a person's first and last name.  I don't want people to only enter one or the other.

Is there a way to check for a `space` character between 2 words and another `space` character along with any `letter`, `number`, etc  after the 2nd word if it exists?  I think that if the user accidently 'fat-fingers' an extra space after the 2nd word, that should be fine bc there are still only 2 words.

For example:

```
/* the _ character means space */

John               /* not accepted */

John_              /* not accepted */

John_Smith_a       /* not accepted */

John Smith_        /* accepted */
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple approaches that you could use to solve this, I'll review over a few.

**Using the `String.Split()` Method**

You could use the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) method to break up a string into it's individual components based on a delimiter. In this case, you could use a space as a delimiter to get the individual words :

```
// Get your words, removing any empty entries along the way
var words = YourTextBox.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Determine how many words you have here
if(words.Length != 2)
{
     // Tell the user they made a horrible mistake not typing two words here
}
```

**Using a Regular Expression**

Additionally, you could attempt to resolve this via a Regular Expression using the [`Regex.IsMatch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
// Check for exactly two words (and allow for beginning and trailing spaces)
if(!Regex.IsMatch(input,@"^(\s+)?\w+\s+\w+(\s+)?"))
{
     // There are not two words, do something
}
```

The expression itself may look a bit scary, but it can be broken down as follows :

```
^        # This matches the start of your string
(\s+)?   # This optionally allows for a single series of one or more whitespace characters
\w+      # This allows for one or more "word" characters that make up your first word
\s+      # Again you allow for a series of whitespace characters, you can drop the + if you just want one
\w+      # Here's your second word, nothing new here
(\s+)?   # Finally allow for some trailing spaces (up to you if you want them)
```

A "word" character `\w` is a special character in Regular Expressions that can represent a digit, letter or an underscore and is the equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

**Taking Advantage of Regular Expressions using MVC's `RegularExpressionAttribute`**

Finally, since you are using MVC, you could take advantage of the [`[RegularExpressionValidation]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute on your model itself :

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(\s+)?\w+\s+\w+(\s+)?", ErrorMessage = "Exactly two words are required.")]
public string YourProperty { get; set; }
```

This will allow you to simply call the `ModelState.IsValid` within your Controller Action to see if your Model has any errors or not :

```
// This will check your validation attributes like the one mentioned above
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
     // You probably have some errors, like not exactly two words
}
```

Comment: What about an expression to match something like `Cpl\3 John Smith` or `Mr. John Smith`?  I have `@"^(\s+)?[A-Za-z_.-]+\s\w+\s\w+(\s+)?$"`

Comment: Do you want to allow those in addition to your previous case or as a completely separate set? As those technically consist of three words.

Comment: Yes, in addition to my previous case. 3 is the max and minimum

Comment: If you wanted to allow exactly three sets of words, you could append another `\w+` in there, but if you want to allow things like slashes and decimals, then you would need `[\w.\\]+` like `@"^(\s+)?[\w.\\]+\s+\w+\s+\w+(\s+)?$"`. You can [see an example and play around with it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qffP88).

Answer (score 2):

use it like this

```
string s="John_Smith_a"
if (s.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Length > 1)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tag implies MVC here, so I would recommend using the `RegularExpressionAttribute` class:

```
public class YourModel
{
    [RegularExpression(@"[^\w\s\w$]", ErrorMessage = "You must have exactly two words separated by a space.")]
    public string YourProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to use **regular expressions** with the `IsMatch` method like this:

```
Regex.IsMatch("One Two", @"^\w+\s\w+\s?$")
```

Returns `true` if the input is a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
Match m = Regex.Match(this.yourTextBox.Text, @"[^\w\s\w$]", String.Empty);
if (m.Success)
  //do something
else
  //do something else
```

With my very limited knowledge of regular expressions, I believe that this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (str.Split(' ').Length == 2)
{
   //Do Something
}
```

str is the variable holding your string to compare